# Computing Confidence Intervals for Coefficients in Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, confidence-interval, regression-coefficients

After fitting a logistic regression model in R using `model <- glm(y~x,family='binomial')` I can obtain the confidence intervals for the fitted coefficients using `confint(model)`, but I want to know how to manually compute these values. In the case of a linear model `lin_mod <- lm(y~x)` I can just do the following to obtain a 95% confidence interval for the slope coefficient:

```
CI_lower <- coefficients(lin_mod)[2] - 1.96*summary(lin_mod)$coefficients[2,2]
CI_upper <- coefficients(lin_mod)[2] + 1.96*summary(lin_mod)$coefficients[2,2]
```

Where `coefficients(lin_mod)[2]` is the estimated value of the coefficient, and `summary(lin_mod)$coefficients[2,2]` is corresponding standard error.

However when I use this same process to compute the confidence interval of the fitted coefficients of a logistic regression, the values don't agree with the output from `confint`. Below is an example using some randomly generated data:

```
x <- rnorm(n=100, mean=5, sd=2)
y_prob <- plogis(x, location=5, scale=1)
y <- sapply(y_prob, function(p) rbinom(1, 1, p))
model <- glm(y~x, family='binomial')

summary(model)$coefficients
#               Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) -3.8998231  0.8838826 -4.412150 1.023490e-05
# x            0.7963213  0.1746632  4.559183 5.135303e-06

CI_lower <- coefficients(model)[2] - 1.96*summary(model)$coefficients[2,2] # = 0.4539815 
CI_upper <- coefficients(model)[2] + 1.96*summary(model)$coefficients[2,2] # = 1.138661 

confint(model)
#                  2.5 %    97.5 %
# (Intercept) -5.8044657 -2.313925
# x            0.4843258  1.173998
```

As you can see, manually computing the 95% CI around the x-coefficient yielded `(0.4539815,1.138661)` whereas computing it using `confint` yielded `(0.4843258,1.173998)`. So my question is, how is `confint` computing this confidence interval, and why does my estimate differ? From some additional tests on larger samples I can see that the two estimates converge in the large-N limit, but I'm interested in what's going on for small N, in particular why the CI produced by `confint` is not symmetric about the coefficient estimate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just discovered that [someone answered this question in another post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/5320/60065). The answer is, `confint` uses [profile confidence intervals](http://www.math.umt.edu/patterson/ProfileLikelihoodCI.pdf), whereas I was computing a [Wald confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) (which can equivalently be computed using `confint.default`).