# SPSS vs R confidence interval

Tags: r, regression, logistic, confidence-interval, spss

When I performed logistic regression and generated a confidence interval of the odds ratio with R using `confint`, it gave a different confidence interval than the one generated in SPSS. However, when I use `confint.default` in R instead, the confidence intervals were the same as those generated in SPSS. Can someone explain why I am getting different confidence intervals from SPSS vs R with `confint` and `confint.default`?

Comment: `confint.default` uses "asymptotic normality" while `confint` is a generic method which uses more appropriate calculation for your particular model, if it exists.   Can you show a small toy example with inputs, code and outputs, which we can reproduce?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95 and the questions linked to it