# Calculating confidence intervals for coefficients in ordinal logistic regression

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, t-distribution, ordered-logit, polr

I've fitted an ordinal logistic regression model in R using `MASS::polr` and I am looking to compute confidence intervals for the fitted coefficients.

Here is the (cropped) model output:

```
polr(formula = response ~ group, data = df, 
    Hess = TRUE, method = "logistic")

Coefficients:
        Value       Std. Error t value
group1  -0.5279     0.7007     -0.7533
group2  -1.0144     0.7163     -1.4163
```

My 2 questions:

1. What distribution should I use? My natural assumption was the t-distribution but I've seen instances online of people using the normal.
2. If the t-distribution, how many degrees of freedom should I use? My hunch was the residual degrees of freedom of the model (`n - p`) but I've seen instances of people using `1` as well.

Comment: Have a look [at this question with 3 answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95/5320#5320)